# Can't seem to save data in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, logging, cakephp-3.x

So I want to save array of data as test in my database.

My code for saving is in ResultLog.php

```
<?php

namespace Alis\Mall\Alpen\Domain\Log;

use Alis\MultiDbConnection\ClientDbConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ResultLog
{
    private $MallExportResultLog;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $MallExportResultLog = TableRegistry::get('MallExportResultLog');
    }
    /**
     */
    public function save()
    {
        $MallExportResultLog->setConnection(ClientDbConnectionManager::getInstance()->getConnection());

        $data = [
            'stream_name' => "test",
            'stream_version' => 1,
            'event_type' => "test",
            'data' => "test"
        ];

        $entity = $MallExportResultLog->newEntity($data);
        if (! $MallExportResultLog->save($entity)) {
            throw new \Exception($entity->errors());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try to call it in the ExportAllProductsShell.php, in `$resultlog = new ResultLog();` but it seems like it doesn't work.

Here is how I do it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Alis\Mall\Alpen\UseCase\ExportAllProducts;
use Alis\Mall\Alpen\Domain\Log\ResultLog;

/**
 * ExportAllProductsShell shell command.
 */
class ExportAllProductsShell extends Shell
{

    public function main()
    {
        $this->out('Start Execute.');
        $export = new ExportAllProducts();
        $export->export();

        $resultlog = new ResultLog();

        $this->out('Finish Execute.');
    }
}
```

The ExportAllProducts() execute, but the ResultLog() cannot.

What is wrong or lacking?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$this->MallExportResultLog`?

Answer (score 0):

From the snippets of code you've provided you never call `$resultlog->save()`. If that was omitted by mistake, you should then check that your entity doesn't contain any validation errors that would prevent saving.

`debug($entity->getErrors());`

Will let you see any validation errors in your entity.